# Can someone convert this Hashing method from C# to VB?

Tags: c#, vb.net

```
  public static string CalculateSHA1(string text, Encoding enc)
{
    byte[] buffer = enc.GetBytes(text);
    SHA1CryptoServiceProvider cryptoTransformSHA1 = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();
    string hash = BitConverter.ToString(cryptoTransformSHA1.ComputeHash(buffer)).Replace("-", "");
    return hash;
}
```

THANKS!

VStudio keeps yelling at me for just what I have so far most specifically the bracket at the end of Byte?:

```
Private Sub CalculateSHA1(ByVal text As String, ByVal enc As Encoding)
    Dim buffer As Byte[] = enc.GetBytes(text);

End Sub
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about this?

```
Public Shared Function CalculateSHA1(text As String, enc As Encoding) As String
    Dim buffer As Byte() = enc.GetBytes(text)
    Dim cryptoTransformSHA1 As New SHA1CryptoServiceProvider()
    Dim hash As String = BitConverter.ToString(cryptoTransformSHA1.ComputeHash(buffer)).Replace("-", "")
    Return hash
End Function
```

VB.NET doesn't use `[]` for arrays, it uses `()` instead.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Andrew's answer, there are [quite a few simple converter tools on the web.](http://www.google.com/search?source=ig&hl=en&rlz=&=&q=visual+basic+to+C%23+converter&aq=f&oq=&aqi=g4g-s1g5)  I tend to [use this one with good success when needed.](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/)

Comment: Can I also add [this one](http://www.carlosag.net/Tools/CodeTranslator/) to the list of good converters - this one has succeeded in some cases where the developer fusion one failed

Answer (score 0):

Did you try

```
Dim buffer as Byte() = enc.GetBytes(text)
```

no semicolon?

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Shared Function CalculateSHA1(ByVal text As String, ByVal enc As Encoding) As String
    Dim buffer As Byte() = enc.GetBytes(text)
    Dim cryptoTransformSHA1 As New SHA1CryptoServiceProvider()
    Dim hash As String = BitConverter.ToString(cryptoTransformSHA1.ComputeHash(buffer)).Replace("-", "")
    Return hash
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the brackets to parentheses:

```
Dim buffer As Byte() = enc.GetBytes(text);
```